# Get the Html Tag as string

Tags: php, html

I have a script that gets embed code for me.I am using php simple html dom parser.The code i am using is like this :

```
        foreach ($html->find('object embed') as $embedCode)
            {

              echo $embedCode;

            }
```

and the out put is :

```
        <embed width="100%" height="320" flashvars="config=http://server0.stream2k.com/playerjw/vConfigCdn.php?vkey=c2053010dadfdd331145" 
        allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" 
        src="http://server0.stream2k.com/playerjw/player-licensed56.swf" 
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent">
```

but it's showing in my browser as a flash screen.I want to print it as a single string.

Can anyone tell me how can i get it as a single string not the video screen.

Thanks in advance

The return of GetMovie() :

```
               <embed wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-  flash"             
               pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"  
               src="http://server0.stream2k.com/playerjw/player- licensed56.swf"                  
               width="100%" height="320" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" flashvars="config=http://server0.stream2k.com/playerjw/vConfigCdn.php?vkey=f3513b19d1149102e116" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by single string?

Comment: as it sounds...in a single(single means one(one means-->1)) variable $a=desiredTagsAsString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use htmlspecialchars:

```
 foreach ($html->find('object embed') as $embedCode)
            {

              echo htmlspecialchars($embedCode);

            }
```

Comment: i need to throw the htmlspecialchars to database as the source code..is it possible?i tried with mysel_escape_string..but it's not working

Comment: Yes, sure. Why not? Just remember about mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: mysql_escape_string($movieObject->GetEmbed())

Comment: but it's showing warning that mysql_escape_string --->access denied..i also tried with mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: It seems your $movieObject->GetEmbed() returns incorect value. Just for experiment you could try base64_encode/base64_decode for db record saving: base64_encode($movieObject->GetEmbed()). If it works, you can use base64_encode then or keep trying find out the problem in your $movieObject->GetEmbed(). Unfortunetely I don't know what  return $movieObject->GetEmbed()

Comment: So GetMovie of GetEmbed? You wrote that you call GetEmbed in the query.

Comment: ya it's GetEmbed..i am concern about the query..fact is give me way to avoid mysql_escape_string

Comment: Are you sure you have a connection to DB. Access denied means you havn't it

Comment: all data are inserting from the same object except the embed code..it says mysql_escape_string(embed here) accepts 2 parameter..access denied for user..

Comment: could you try to insert simple string, smth like 'test' instead of mysql_escape_string(embed here) and mysql_escape_string('test'). Which result you get?

Comment: actually server is not allowing me to do mysql_escape_string..:(....and if i don't do that that causes many mysql errors as it's a long string with urls and all...you know

Comment: ya i tried with base64_encode...but it will create complexity in my system..so avoided it..but it works..simply the warning was showing...thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

Try to put output string in htmlspecialchars: `echo htmlspecialchars($embedCode);`

Comment: Can i pick it like : $code=htmlspecialchars($embedCode);and send to database?

Comment: Yes, inside your table the code will be stored like this: &lt;strong&gt;...i.e the HTML tags will be encoded in such way, that browser will not interpret them as a code, but as simple text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
<pre>
    &#60;embed width="100%" height="320" flashvars="config=http://server0.stream2k.com/playerjw/vConfigCdn.php?vkey=c2053010dadfdd331145" 
    allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" 
    src="http://server0.stream2k.com/playerjw/player-licensed56.swf" 
    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent">
​</pre>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

Try add this before your "for" loop:

```
echo '<xmp>';
```

this will echo all charactors but not display as html code.